# After adding @Future annotation to entity - TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, validation

I am using Spring Framework 4 & Hibernate 4.

I added @Future constraint into my entity and after that I am running into Exception:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
```

After some research I found out that it is caused by including `id` in hashCode method, if I remove the `id` from hashCode method then the Exception is gone and it works as intended.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id.hashCode();
    // Code intentionally omitted
    return result;
}
```

**Question is**: Why can't I use the `id` in `hashCode` method like this? How should I change it?

Entity code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITY")
public class ActivityEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Future
    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_FROM", nullable = false, length = 19)
    private Date activityFrom;

    // Code of other attributes intentionally omitted

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getActivityFrom() {
        return activityFrom;
    }

    public void setActivityFrom(Date activityFrom) {
        this.activityFrom = activityFrom;
    }

    // Code of other methods intentionally omitted

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        // Code intentionally omitted
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

I changed attribute id:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", length = 10)
private Long id;
```

I changed hashCode method:

`int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: The stacktrace you posted is not enough as it hides the root cause of the exception. But anyway, i suspect a null pointer ;)

You have two issues with your code. The first issue is that you are assuming a non null id at all time, which is (most likely) not true in case of a new entity which is not persisted. So fix this by checking on null in your hashcode method.

Eclipse can help you in generating equals/hashcode methods, which are close to what i normally need to code.

The second issue is a not so obvious one. As you are using hibernate, any entity instance might be a proxy if this entity was lazy loaded. As a side effect the proxy, which is a Implemented as a subclass, holds also these attributes and you might not fetch the one you expect. Intercepting fields directly is not implemented, as far as i know.

So to fix the second issue you really have to use the "non-final !" getter methods in  hashcode/equals, which are intercepted by the proxy and delegated to your real entity instance.